# Python Multiprocessing over hundreds of files

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pandas, multiprocessing

I have hundreds to thousands of files that I'm trying to parallelize during processing but I'm having trouble with the logic.

My goal is to either have 8 threads work on one process (not sure if possible due to processing on pandas dataframes) or have 8 threads each work on 1 file independently.

Below is some simplified code from my application. I honestly don't really know what it's doing though. When I run the application, it starts flying through the files but when I'm printing the file name they are all out of order. After a couple minutes it's slows down really slow but is still printing random field names that are out of order. It looks like stuff is being appended to the output file but I can't tell where they're coming from.

Do I need to chunk my file list into and get 8 files at a time and process it that way? Or is my code just incorrect in how I"m going about this? I've tried the Pool and Process classes but neither seem to work for this use case.

```
import os.path
from os import path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Process
import multiprocessing as mp
from concurrent import futures as cf
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


def apply_ref_to_ind(input_df, temp_ref_df):

    final_df = pd.merge(input_df, temp_ref_df, how='outer', on='CODE')
    final_df['CALC2'] = final_df['CALC1'] - temp_ref_df['CALC1']

    return final_df


def worker(input_file):
    """Worker process for operating on partitioned reference data"""

    temp_input = pd.read_csv(input_file, dtype=str)
    code = temp_input['CODE'].unique()[0]
    temp_ref_df = ref_df.loc[ref_df['CODE'] == code]

    print(input_file)
    return_df = apply_ref_to_ind(temp_input, temp_ref_df)

    if path.exists("output_file.csv"):
        return_df[final_layout].to_csv('output_file.csv', index=None)
    else:
        return_df[final_layout].to_csv('output_file.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_list = ['file.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']  # etc...
    ref_df = pd.read_csv('reference.csv')
    final_layout = ['ID', 'CODE', 'CALC1', 'CALC2']

    pool = Pool(8)  # Create a multiprocessing Pool
    pool.map(worker, [file for file in file_list])  # process data_inputs iterable with pool
```

Comment: Yes, you can't rely on the processes occuring in a particular order

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I figured they would go in the order of the files in the file list which makes it hard for me to see if it's really working or not. It's been running for a couple hours now but it looks like the output file got overwritten for some reason and started over again.

Comment: No, if you expect things to run in parallel, how can you expect them to run in order? The list will be *consumed* in order, but after each item is handed off to the next worker the pool of processes, you cannot guarantee that the worker that got handed something first will finish working first etc, etc

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah I know they will not finish in order so I think that's why I was confused. They are reading the files in order, just finishing in different times. That makes sense now. Thanks!